# Bulk Insert Task Error in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, bulkinsert

While running ssis Bulk insert i got the following error.

> An error occurred with the following error message: "Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.".

To solve the problem i have change the connection timeout to `0` and to `5` . That did not work .

I also reviewed the data on row 1 column 1.

Comment: I have made some changes to my flat file. I am getting the following error now."XML parsing: line 2, character 0, incorrect document syntax".

Comment: What is the field and row terminator you are using, and what does the first row looks like?

Comment: column 5 (Snow).Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 11

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5caa8c0a-2328-4c9e-9894-eaba12e8196a/data-conversion-error-during-bulk-insert?forum=sqlgetstarted

Comment: That worked . Thanks alot

Comment: i posted it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"In order to avoid these kinds of issues, I always import all fields as varchar fields into a staging table, then convert them into the data type required.  You will have much more control."*

You can get more details from the following link:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5caa8c0a-2328-4c9e-9894-eaba12e8196a/data-conversion-error-during-bulk-insert?forum=sqlgetstarted